# How to set default conda / python environment for R

Tags: python, r, shiny, conda, reticulate

I'm new to R and shiny.

I setup a server and it mostly works, but R code that references the boto3 library fails with

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'"
```

However, if I add this code at the top of the file:

```
library(reticulate)

use_condaenv("/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python_3x_nix")
```

Then, it works.

Even more confusing - once it works, I can remove those two lines and it continues to work for a while. Then, I suppose some kind of context object gets flushed and the errors come back.

So it would seem that the issue is just getting R to run with the correct conda environment (which I setup through conda externally) by default.

Can anyone tell me whether this is possible, and if so, then how?

Comment: I'm seeing some posts that indicate I have to create my R environment from within my conda environment, so in this case I would be running R from 
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python_3x_nix/

Is that correct?

Comment: Ping me back if that duplicate doesn't work for you and I can reopen. But mainly, you can set the RETICULATE_PYTHON variable in your .Rprofile and that will then define the default Python without having to set it each time. As for Conda R environments - no that doesn't sound right; native R installs should work fine with Conda Python environments.

Comment: I had actually tried updating the .Rprofile file unsuccessfully, but I wrestled with it and the subtle difference is that it needs to point all the way to /bin/python:

Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON="/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python_3x_nix/bin/python")

This works!